# Как убить неубиваемый процесс в Linux

Tags: linux, процесс, kill

Есть процесс который нужно убить, пробовал `kill пид` и `kill -9 пид`, но процесс не убивается, что делать?

Comment: sudo kill -9  даже не помогает?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor да

Comment: и что за процесс такой?

Comment: Зомби какой-нибудь небось

Comment: да просто `sync && sync && reboot` - гарантировано все подчищает

Comment: @KoVadim, не видели ещё как иногда такие процессы не дают перезапустить систему?

Comment: Это означает, что он находится в непрерываемой спячке *TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE*. Обычно свидетельствует об ожидании I/O. Смотрите, кто и что пытается делать с вводом-выводом.

Comment: да, бывает всякое. Но обычно при этом ещё и LA большое.  Но, обычно нужно пытаться убить не сами зомби, а их родителя. В этом случае их родителем обычно сразу станет init, а он знает, что с ними делать.

Comment: @KoVadim, непонятно, почему вы решили, что я говорю про зомби...

Comment: видимо нужно будет добавить в текст разделитель мыслей, палочку какою-то...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

На самом деле возможны два варианта:

1. Этот "неубиваемый процесс - зомби. В статусе стоит "z". Убить его
   невозможно т.к. он уже и так - мёртвый. Надо найти родителя и
   перестартовать его.
2. Этот процесс мониторится другим процессом (скоре всего - родителем) и при его убийстве немедленно перезапускается. Опять же - убить родителя. А уж потом - сам процесс.

Comment: Это был не зомби, спасибо за ответ.